# Disable application only for tablet

Tags: android, android-screen-support, android-screen

I am wondering how could I disable application for tablet I mean user cannot download application when he is using tablet.

```
<supports-screens
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="false"/>
```

Is this is right approache? There is some devices that have large screens, i.e Galaxy Note or Samsung Mega. Are they belong to xlargeScreen?

If I disable it would be any device(phones) that cannot download application too?

Answer (score 0):

7" screens are both large and xlarge. So you must turn it false too.

More info here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html